# Allow Many Origins in EnableCors()

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a MVC web API with GET method called GetNames.

When I want to call myapi.com/controller/GetNames from AJAX in another website, I am getting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

So In my MVC Web API Code,

I added this in my WebApiConfig:

```
  config.EnableCors();
```

And I added this to my Controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebsite.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public string GetNames(string requestKey)
```

What if many websites are calling this method?

I want to allow **many** origins, and even better if I can allow **all origins**, not just defined ones.

Comment: Use `*` for `origins`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation on [`EnableCorsAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.cors.enablecorsattribute.enablecorsattribute(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_2):

> *origins*: Comma-separated list of origins that are allowed to access the resource. Use "*" to allow all.

So your attribute will now look something like this for a list of origins:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://site1.com,http://site2.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Or this for all origins:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```